# Did the emails with notifications about inbox messages stop?

Tags: bug, status-completed, email, global-inbox, email-notification

Depending on the settings chosen in preferences, a user is supposed to be shown the recent notifications if they have some notifications in the inbox and they haven't checked it for some period (The choices are a week/a day/3 hours. The other option is to turn notification off.)

**Question.** As far as I can tell, I am no longer getting such emails. Can somebody else confirm the same problem? Is the problem on my side, or is there are such email no longer sent by Stack Exchange.

**Updated question.** Are there also some other users who do not get *any* emails from Stack Exchange altogether. (Such as newsletters, filter subscriptions or other things which I did not think of.)

For a long time I had this settings on one day. After I suspected that I had not received such an email - despite not looking into my inbox for a longer time - I changed this to "3 hours" yesterday. I am pretty sure that I have some unread notifications which are older than one day. And I definitely have some notifications which are older than 3 hours. (At the moment, I have still not looked into the inbox - and I am shown the red number with the number of messages. I will not look there at least for the next day on two - to make sure that I am eligible for receiving such an email. Mainly because I want to be able to check whether this has been solved - if it is indeed a bug.)

The last time I received an email with such notifications (having subject of the form "n new items in your Stack Exchange inbox") was on December 12.

I am also subscribed to newsletters from some sites. The most recent I see in my inbox is from December 10. So there is a possibility that I am no longer getting *any* emails from Stack Exchange whatsoever.

In case it might be relevant, I am using gmail. I have checked whether I have such email in the spam folder and I have also looked in the "secondary" tabs Social and Promotions.

EDIT: I have tried to subscribe to [some filters](https://stackexchange.com/filters/406430/functional-analysis-mse-and-mo), just to see whether I will receive messages from them. I got the message: "Confirmation email sent. Please confirm your subscription." But I did not receive the confirmation email. (And I will later see whether I'll receive email about new question in that filter - but since I did not get the confirmation email, this seems rather unlikely.)

EDIT 2: Following the advice given in the comments, I have changed my settings to another email address - and I have already received one notification email. Still, it would be nice being able to switch back to the original address at some point.

---

Here is a screenshot from mail email preferences:

[image: screenshot showing preferences]

Here is a screenshot with the subscribed newsleters:

[image: screenshot with newsletters]

Comment: Hmmm I would venture a guess that this might be related to Google's recent outages. You have been generated three more inbox emails since then; two on Dec 15 and one on Dec 16. The first one bounced, presumably due to those issues, and the other two were just dropped *because* the first one bounced and I believe future emails to a bounced address get suppressed. I'd wonder how many emails are being ignored because of Google's issue...

Comment: @animuson Is it possible that changing my Email Settings to another address and than back could solve the issue for me? (I will add that today I received an email from SO with the subjection: "The Overflow #52: The semantic future of the web". But so far no notification emails.)

Comment: I don't believe so. This isn't something happening in our system, but with the email delivery provider we use to send them. They are being dropped when they reach that service and possibly the only fix is to remove it from the suppression list there. Changing to another email address entirely would work, because it would not be suppressed by the delivery network. Presuming you want to use a different email temporarily.

Comment: @Martin Have you tried switching back to the other address since? I'm assuming that whatever issues were in play at the time have been resolved, but would love to confirm.

Comment: @AdamLear After your comment, I tried to switch back to the address I used to have there. I have received two such emails since then - so it seems to be working. (Although this is a rather small sample.) Did Stack Exchange made some changes? (From the comment posted by animuson it seemed that using a different email was the only solution.)

Comment: @Martin No changes on our end that I'm aware of. I think animuson was right and the issue was somewhere outside our control. Thanks for trying it out. I'll mark this report as resolved, but if you run into email issues again, please feel free to post a new one.